# Which Python method is more efficient for checking powers of 2?

Tags: python, algorithm, bitwise-operators, space-complexity

Consider the following two Python implementations for checking if a number is a power of 2:

**Method 1: Using Math.log()**

```
import math

def is_power_of_two(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return False
    v = math.log(n, 2)
    return int(v) == v
```

**Method 2: Using Bitwise Operator**

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
    return n > 0 and ((n & (n - 1)) == 0)
```

Both methods return the correct results. However, can you explain the difference in time and space efficiency between these two methods?

Could you explain the computational complexity of each method and identify any scenarios where one method would be more efficient or appropriate to use than the other?

Comment: That's an odd question, since the first one isn't even correct.

Comment: The first won't work for very large integers. Try it on `2 ** 100 + 1`.

Comment: The first one can be made more efficient as `return n > 0 and math.log(n, 2).is_integer()`.

Comment: @interjay Try it on `2**29` and `2**48 - 1`.

Comment: If you just want to know which is faster then you can time it, e.g. with the timeit module. But I would argue that if this matters then you may be using the wrong language.

Comment: @KellyBundy Those examples are fixed if you use `math.log2` instead of `math.log` (which should also be faster). But the issue with larger numbers will remain with any floating-point solution.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, firstly, the first method is indeed correct. Secondly, instead of hastily dismissing what you fail to understand, it would be better to seek clarification. Engaging in informed discussions benefits everyone involved.

Comment: It's not correct, we even showed you counter-examples where it fails.

Comment: While floating-point precision in Python could cause rare discrepancies, it's not indicative of an error in the first method's logic. For very large numbers, I agree, the second method is more reliable. However, for most use cases, the first method remains valid. Let's keep the facts straight.

Comment: I didn't say the "logic" is wrong. You didn't ask about the "logic". You asked about those Python implementations. And you asked about time and space efficiency. That's understood as being about growth towards infinite size. So "very large numbers" matters. If you have some small range in mind, you need to say that, and likely shouldn't say "complexity" (depends on your range). And 2^29 isn't even very large.

Comment: Your fixation on edge cases with large numbers is skewing the conversation. Yes, computational complexity considers scale, but it's not detached from practical use. Absence of a specified range implies all positive integers are fair game. For a majority of this scope, the first method holds. Focus on the broader perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`math.log` converts the argument to a floating-point representation and computes the logarithm there. Therefore, should the conversion end up being inexact so will be the result. For "double" precision (i.e. 64-bits) floats that gives you 2^53 upper bound.

So only the later one is correct. As for what the speed goes, in CPython I doubt you will see any significant difference but a few integer instructions are definitely going to be faster than computing log in floating point (+ the conversion), in general.

Out of curiosity, you could also try:

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
    return (1 << (n.bit_length() - 1)) == n
```

Comment: or `return n > 0 and n.bit_count() == 1` ?

Comment: @slothrop Absolutely, that's even better! I was not aware that Python got `bit_count`, thank you very much for bringing this to my attention!

Comment: Ha, I was actually thinking of something similar to yours with `bit_length`, went to look for it in the docs, and realised `bit_count` is there now as of Python 3.10!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and for providing another efficient method.

Comment: *"math.log converts the argument to a floating-point representation and computes the logarithm there"* - Which floating-point representation? It's able to compute `math.log(2**123456, 2)`, while `float(2**123456)` crashes.

Comment: @KellyBundy https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b7aadb4583b040ddc8564896b91f4e5e571c82d6/Modules/mathmodule.c#L2234

Comment: @slothrop Not sure that's faster (would be interesting to benchmark the different solutions with very large ints, like n=2^i for i from 1000000 to 1000029). But it does have the advantage of only using constant space (I think).

Comment: @EcirHana interesting, so the code path with *"Here the conversion to double overflowed, but it's possible to compute the log anyway.  Clear the exception and continue."* is what takes care of 2**123456

Comment: @slothrop [Looks like](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDLTsNADBTX_Yo5sbshjRJeQlXDr6AUnNZS46w2jgSq-iVceoGP4mvYJCC42JY9M7bn_TO86b6X8_lj1Hb18HWxbmPfQbkjVnAX-qiIFKhRY-g1xAE1rLVG8IgSjbzAOcElUlih8h51jdIbV2GzSc1iy_p0INnp3vk_hPzjL5jnfhR187AyaUExaOTgfDGEA-uBhQbnjTFtH8FgQWxkR64qs-wux5yubkq_NkCInKTYp3IgHUO6uLWS4vE6y_hkU39SoUllfmkiAZoQHYtbvnWUL-wcMnZbinU6fcYt8q09albR_fq2qNqTzUF-sfDHyV9HvwE) the bitcount one is the slowest of the three correct ones. And now that I think of it, I vaguely remember writing `n >= 1 == n.bit_count()` recently on SO somewhere...

Comment: @slothrop But it indeed only takes [constant space](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVBBTsMwEBRXv2JOxI7SKOFCVTWc-UNVRSZ1W0uObTlbRIV4CZde4FG8BtspAi5e7-7szO68f_ozHZ29XD5OtF8sv24e9ehdIFCQgxqlMW6AnEAjY-rFhwkdiqJgFg9oIO0OnFvcIj4LtEKg69AIxlus17FYP2nqjbIHOnLxi7B_5mfM4E6WeG627F-JRbl6oqA9F_XkjSajrZpig-1dgIa22LRNWd5XSGG5RYm7FQNs3DXvoWOSsCph8xWpjXhUJJYhiaRUPUvD1fz3QUfxffEaMQdFfbZj149qdOHMxabdrqq3osIVnpmcz0TzqJgNvfr64-83). Still 12 kB, though, I wonder why. Edit: Oh I think it's `eval` overhead...